# Redis and Postgresql on same machine: vm.overcommit_memory=?

Tags: postgresql, redis, sysctl

In the Redis documentation it clearly states that `vm.overcommit_memory` should be set to `1` to ensure background saving newer fails: http://redis.io/topics/faq

HOWEVER

In postgresql documentation it says, that `vm.overcommit_memory` should be set to `2` to avoid the post master process does not get killed by the oom killer: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/kernel-resources.html

Now, this is of cause contradictory. What should I do?

My redis db's have a limit of 20GB. The server has 252GB physical RAM. Postgresql rarely uses more than 100GB physical ram.

PS: I'm on ubuntu 14, Redis 3.0 and Postgresql 9.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may go for the Redis recommendation, as the PostgreSQL packages for Ubuntu already implement the approach mentioned in the documentation against an ill-advised OOM kill of the postmaster process.

It's just after the section you're refering to in the doc.
Excerpt from [Linux Memory Overcommit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT)

> Another approach, which can be used with or without altering
>   vm.overcommit_memory, is to set the process-specific oom_score_adj
>   value for the postmaster process to -1000, thereby guaranteeing it
>   will not be targeted by the OOM killer. The simplest way to do this is
>   to execute
>
> echo -1000 > /proc/self/oom_score_adj
>
> in the postmaster's startup script just before invoking the
>   postmaster. Note that this action must be done as root, or it will
>   have no effect; so a root-owned startup script is the easiest place to
>   do it. If you do this, you may also wish to build PostgreSQL with
>   -DLINUX_OOM_SCORE_ADJ=0 added to CPPFLAGS. That will cause postmaster child processes to run with the normal oom_score_adj value of zero, so
>   that the OOM killer can still target them at need.

On Ubuntu 14, the `pg_ctlcluster` script that starts a postgres instance has this:

```
   # have the postmaster start with increased OOM killer protection; 9.1 and
    # later has builtin support for resetting the adjustment of child processes
    if ($action eq 'start' && $version >= '9.1') {
        if (-w '/proc/self/oom_score_adj') {
            open F, '>/proc/self/oom_score_adj';
            print F "-900\n";
            close F;
        }
    }
```

so it assigns a fixed `-900` to the postmaster's OOM score,

and `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_config pg_config --cflags` says:

> -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -pie -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 **-DLINUX_OOM_SCORE_ADJ=0** -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g

So the `postmaster` should never be selected by the OOM killer, but child backend process (one per connection) can.

Comment: Extraordinary good answer :-)